# Group string element in array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object array like this:

```
var input = [{ time: '11:01:00', data: 'a,b,c' }, { time: '11:01:11', data: 'a,b,c' }]
```

After I call:

```
var output1 = input.map(a => a.data);
console.log(output1);
```

The result would be:

```
[
  "a,b,c",
  "a,b,c"
]
```

Now I want the final output will be:

```
[
  {data: ["a","a"]},
  {data: ["b","b"]},
  {data: ["c","c"]},
]
```

I have tried many way but no hope to do this.

Comment: Can input have data like 'a,b,c,d,e' ?

Comment: Yes it will be a string with comma

Comment: You want to group based on the similarity of the values or based on their position? If the matrix transposition is what you want, then you can accept that answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operation is essentially a matrix transposition, let's code it as such:

```js
let transpose = matrix => matrix[0].map((_, col) => 
    matrix.map(row => row[col]))

//

var input = [{ time: '...', data: 'a,b,c' }, { time: '...', data: 'x,y,z' }]


let result = transpose(
    input.map(o => o.data.split(','))
).map(data => ({data}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.flatMap()` with `Array.slice()` to get an array of strings. Then reduce it to an object, with equal strings grouped together, and convert back to an array using `Object.values()`:

```js
const input = [{ time: '11:01:00', data: 'a,b,c' }, { time: '11:01:11', data: 'a,b,c' }]

const result = Object.values(
  input.flatMap(o => o.data.split(','))
    .reduce((acc, c) => {
      if(!acc[c]) acc[c] = { data: [] }

      acc[c].data.push(c)

      return acc
    }, {})
)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```js
var input = [{ time: '11:01:00', data: 'a,b,c' }, { time: '11:01:11', data: 'a,b,c' }];

var output1 = input.map(a => a.data);

// Let's split the strings in order to have an array ('a', 'b', 'c')
output1 = output1.map( (data) => data.split(',') );

let valueMap = {};

// Loop through all the values
for (let list of output1) {
   for (let element of list) {
      // Use a dictionary to group all the identical values
      if (!valueMap[element]) {
          valueMap[element] = [element];
      }
      else {
          valueMap[element].push(element);
      }
   } 
}

// Get the values from the object and map it with the desired structure
let result =  Object.values(valueMap).map( (lista) => ({ data: lista }) );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

A single liner.

```js
var input = [{ time: '11:01:00', data: 'a,b,c' }, { time: '11:01:11', data: 'a,b,c' }]


var output1 = input.map(a => a.data.split(','))[0].map((_, idx) => {return {data: input.map(a => a.data.split(',')[idx])}});

console.log(output1);
```